# Setting cart amount limits for different currencies in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

recently I'm using this code to limit the cart amount:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'cldws_set_min_total');

function cldws_set_min_total() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        // Set minimum cart total
        $minimum_cart_total = 100;
        // A Minimum of 100 AUD is required before checking out.
        $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;
        // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total
      
        if( $total <= $minimum_cart_total  ) {
            // Display our error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s %s is required before checking out.</strong>'
                .'<br />Current cart\'s total: %s %s',
                $minimum_cart_total,
                get_option( 'woocommerce_currency'),
                $total,
                get_option( 'woocommerce_currency')),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

but this works for the default currency (USD).
I have another currency on the store but it uses same amount for it

exampl:

Maximum amount in USD: 1000
Maximum amount in any other currency is: 1000

So how to add variable to set it for other currencies

THx in advance

Comment: what currency conversion method are you using, plugin?

Comment: i'm using Curcy switcher

https://docs.villatheme.com/?item=woocommerce-multi-currency